# how to get unique document path as a string?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

The code below generates a document with a unique document path. how do I get this unique document path?

`db.collection("Jobs").document().set(job);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the #kotlin code to get ID of document that created by .add() function

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
.collection(collectionReferencePath)
.get().addOnSuccessListener { querySnapshots ->
  querySnapshots.documents.forEach { documentSnapshot ->
      val idUnique = documentSnapshot.id //This is the Unique Id

  }
}.addOnFailureListener {
  it.printStackTrace()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `set` to a variable, after it resolves you can run `.id` on it which will give you its id.

At that point, the path is something you could create by doing "Jobs/" + id.

I know the below is Javascript code and not Java (like the tag on your question), but it should work something like this:

```
let doc = db.collection("Jobs").doc()
doc.set(job).then(() => { 
    let id = doc.id
})
```